# Ajax call for JSON file not working where it would with XML

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've used ajax to pull data from XML files several times recently, but when I try copying the code and changing the format to JSON I'm not getting any html data in my divs.  Console is error free.

```
<script>
        $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "companyInfo.json",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(json){
                    $(document).find("#companyName").html(json.companyName);
                    $(document).find("#companyLogo").src(json.companyLogo);
                    $(document).find("#contactName").html(json.contactName);
                    $(document).find("#contactStdNum").html(json.contactStdNum);
                    $(document).find("#contactProgram").html(json.contactProgram);
                    $(document).find("#contactSlate").html(json.contactSlate);
                }
            } );    

        } )
        </script>
```

JSON file (companyInfo.json):

```
{
"companyName":"Crane Poole and Schmidt",
"companyLogo":"img/CompanyLogo.png",
"contactName":"Sean Paul",
"contactStdNum":"123456789",
"contactProgram":"Environmental Sustainability",
"contactSlate":"slate";
}
```

I imagine the problem is something simple as a result of stupidity, but if someone could point out what exactly that is I'd be very thankful.

Comment: `$(json)` doesn't do anything because it's not a DOM element or a selector for one. Just use `json.companyName` and so on.

Comment: I initially did that, switched to DOM selector as a debug attempt. Switched main code back in edit, problem remains.

Comment: Have you checked that the result is what it should (`console.log( json )` and `console.log( typeof json )`)? What is `.src()`?

Comment: Also, it seems like the JSON is invalid (semicolon after the last item).

Answer (score 0):

Your result, `json`, is an object. Use `json.propertyname` to access it's contents. Also there's no point in wrapping it as jQuery object, it's not a DOM element.

Also you might want to specify `dataType: "json"` or use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: Big thanks for down-voting my answer after you have edited your question and have applied both my suggestions.